# Evaluating environment variables in github actions workflow

Tags: github, automation, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm positive that this is something easy but I'm not able to track down exactly what I'm looking for.  I have a workflow that performs a build and creates an artifact.  The artifact uses an environment variable in the filename.  So far so good.  Then when I try to pass this file name to [S3 upload action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/s3-upload-action), it isn't found because the environment variable isn't evaluated.  Here is the relevant part of my workflow:

```
  - name: Build project
    run: ./build_project.sh

  - run: ls -l "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build/${FILE_NAME}.zip" # file exists in directory
  - run: echo "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build/${FILE_NAME}.zip" # echo returns the location properly

  - uses: hkusu/s3-upload-action@v2
    id: upload # specify some ID for use in subsequent steps
    with:
      aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      aws-region: "eu-west-2"
      aws-bucket: ${{ secrets.AWS_BUCKET }}
      file-path: "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build/${FILE_NAME}.zip" # Error: file does not exist
      output-file-url: "true" # specify true
  - name: Show URL
    run: echo '${{ steps.upload.outputs.file-url }}' # use this output
```

My actual question is how to replace `"${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build/${FILE_NAME}.zip"` with the file path and name when it actually runs the workflow.  Also, I have tried a few of different combinations of things - no quotes, no curly braces, neither, both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these parameters are passed through to the `s3-upload-action`, the behaviour depends on whether the action expands shell parameters or not, but the input value will be literally

```
${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/build/${FILE_NAME}.zip
```

i.e., unexpanded.

You can use [expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) to work around this:

```yaml
      file-path: ${{ github.workspace }}/build/${{ env.FILE_NAME }}.zip
```

You maybe have assumed that environment variables expand everywhere as they do when evaluated by a shell, such as in a `run:` step, but they don't.